# If I land in London the night of September 9th, will I be required to self isolate until September 22nd or September 23rd?

Tags: uk, london, covid-19, quarantine

Does the count of 14 days include the day I land?
I have someplace important to be at the evening of September 23rd.

Comment: I can not look for the information right now but my BF who is self isolating right now said it is 14 whole days after the day you arrive, so nearer 15 day if you arrive in the morning.

Comment: The count **does not** include the day you land.

Comment: You seem to be working on the assumption you show no symptoms during the 14 day period. That is an unsafe assumption. The 14 days is to give time for symptoms to manifest. If they do manifest then the story changes from that point. Don’t make any firm plans based on an unsafe assumption.

Comment: You have not mentioned your country of origin. There is a large list of exempted countries.

Comment: It largely depends on whether or not you're the government (or a special adviser to it)

Comment: @Strawberry why does it matter if you're the government ? MPs have returned early to avoid isolation

Comment: You'd have to ask the government (not parliament)

Comment: @giraffe86 can you confirm that the place you want to attend on the 23rd is in England? There is a separate law for each of the four parts of the UK.

Answer (score 32):

The [top answer so far](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/159015/27826) quotes the ***guidance*** and not the law.

The **law** is The Health Protection (Coronavirus, International Travel) (England) Regulations 2020, and specifically [Regulation 4(7)(a)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/568/regulation/4/made#regulation-4-7-a)

> (7) P must, on their arrival in England, travel directly to the place at which they are to self-isolate, and must then self-isolate until whichever is the earlier of—
>
> (a) the end of the 14th day after the day on which they arrive in the common travel area, or
> (b) their departure from England.

The fourteenth day after your arrival is 23 September, and the Regulation means that the quarantine period is 14 full days which start when you arrive, but are counted from the midnight after you arrive. If you arrive on 9 September, the remainder of that day **and** the period 10–23 September is your quarantine period and it ends at 2359 on 23 September.

[image: Calendar]

How you choose to act in the last hours of your quarantine (which will be out of normal working hours) is of course entirely up to you.

Comment: I do believe I referenced the appropriate law in my answer below.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, but you also provide contradictory information not asked for and then advocate breaking the law, which seems a peculiar thing to advise a foreign visitor to do. **This** answer is pure fact.

Comment: Your last sentence is a bit odd in the context of your criticism of copper's answer. There is nothing legally special about the "last hours of your quarantine," so "entirely up to you" either means you are encouraging them to break quarantine; or that it is equally up to them throughout quarantine whether they follow quarantine. Which of course, it's not, in the same way "How fast you choose to drive in a 35 mph zone" is not entirely up to you.

Comment: I'm neither encouraging nor discouraging. It is a statement of fact. It's exactly the same as observing a speed limit.

Answer (score 23):

A strict [reading of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk) simply says 14 days, and as such the ***sensible*** thing to do would be to consider that 14 full 24 hour periods, so if you entered the country at 8pm (for example) on the 9th of September, then your isolation period would end at 8pm on the 23rd.

This isn't the sort if thing to skimp on, keep yourself and others safe.

Comment: Your 'strict' reading is not quite correct. The isolation in your example does not end until the **end of day** on September 23rd, not 8pm.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112239/discussion-on-answer-by-moo-if-i-land-in-london-the-night-of-september-9th-will).

Answer (score 7):

From a legal perspective, the fourteen days start on the day **after** your arrival (the legal text is [here](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2020/568/regulation/4/made), see 4.(7)(a)), so legally you are required to self isolate until the end of day on September 23rd. That is, strictly speaking (from a legal perspective) you should not attend the event if you arrive on September 9th.

The remainder of this answer discusses where the 14 days comes from.

From a disease transmission perspective, there is no magic event after an exact 14 days. The 14 days is an estimate of when about 99% of people will have shown symptoms assuming they were infected on Day 1.

There are estimates of the distribution of incubation periods, for example look at the [figure](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7014672/figure/f2/) in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7014672).

Another study ([here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7217033/), **not** peer reviewed) suggests that 'about 10% of patients with COVID-19 would not develop symptoms until 14 days after infection'.

Yet another study ([here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/agm2.12114)) suggests that the incubation period depends on age (see Figure 1 in said article).

Self isolation is just one aspect of prudent Covid behaviour. If you attend your event wear a mask and maintain distance if for no reason other than the precautionary principle.

Comment: There is a magic event after an exact 14 day period - the ability for you to be fined for breaching self isolation disappears. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk Governments have to put arbitrary time periods in effect, because its been shown time and again that the general public generally does not have good judgement - some people will think that they are good to go after a couple of days, some people will stay isolated for the entire period.

Comment: People, remember the rule 'be nice'. This question and its answers are not about any government but that of the UK.

Comment: I am curious about the anonymous downvote? Something incorrect in my answer? Legally, one of the other answers is incorrect.

Comment: @copper.hat - Let me add a non-anonymous downvote then.  I downvote because the OP asks how the 14 days are counted, rather than whether they should ignore the law.  That makes the lack of magic events off topic.  Some parts of your answer are quite good, though, except that they don't make your key point on topic either.

Comment: @JirkaHanika Thank you, I appreciate your directness. I will rearrange my answer.

Comment: And I have rearranged my vote.

Comment: It is interesting to revisit the emotional & mildly abusive interactions in the chat in another answer in the light of empirical reality.

Comment: It is also a little curious that the first answer which quoted both the relevant law and the justification behind the law has the smallest vote count (and many downvotes).